# How do i close a form and open another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm very new to C# as you will probably guess and I'm getting the following error:

`Error  1   'customer_details_form' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'`

I want to close a form if a value is returned and open another form. But I'm struggling on what to in, i.e what is the form called? Is it the namespace I should use or something else.

```
   public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        string fileName = string.Format(tblastname.Text);

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("this customer already exsists");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file found, please create new customer");
            home_form f2 = new home_form();
            this.Hide();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            //if false bring up new customer form.
            customer_details_form f4 = new customer_details_form();
            this.Hide();
            f4.ShowDialog();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory.

Comment: Namespaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
var f4= new customer_details_form.YOUR_FORM_NAME()
```

This is *fully qualified type name* in your assembly (binary)

Comment: Great thankyou. I thought the customer_details_form. was the name of the form. Could you tell me what this is please as i clearly missed the form name out. thanks again.

Comment: that is a *namespace* name, of the form you have.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error since I had a project namespace called Customer and I was trying to use it as a type (I guess this is where good naming conventions come in place) so I just changed the name of the Customer class to CustomerDetails and problem solved. Now my unit test is no longer failing, huzzah!